# (Seg Fault) Read a text file line by line into char double pointer using realloc

Tags: c++, memory, realloc

I am trying to read multiple parameters from a `.txt` file into a `char**`. Each line of the text file contains a parameter.

I wrote the following code but somehow run into seg fault error. I identified the error probably to be the line

`argv[n_lines - 1] = const_cast<char*>(para.c_str());`

where I am tring to assign the parameter (c string) to the slots of `char**`. Somehow, I am not allowed to access the spot.

Can anyone point out what I did wrong and how I can correct the mistake?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>  // Use ifstream

char** file_to_argv(const char* filename) {
  std::string line;
  char**      argv = NULL;
  int         n_lines = 0;  // Number of parameters in total

  std::ifstream file(filename);  // read the entire file
  std::string   para;            // parameter <-> each line in file
  while (std::getline(file, para)) {  // Keep reading in each parameter
    argv = (char**)realloc(argv, sizeof(char*) * ++n_lines);

    /* Check if enough memory is available */
    if (argv = NULL)
      exit(-1);  // memory allocation fails

    // Store parameter into argv array
    argv[n_lines - 1] = const_cast<char*>(para.c_str());
  }

  /* Reallocate one extra slot for the last NULL so that argv is null
     terminated, which is a good identifier when looping */
  argv = (char**)realloc(argv, sizeof(char*) * (n_lines + 1));

  return argv;
}


int main() {
  char** argv = file_to_argv("parameters.txt");
  int i = 0;

  // print out all parameters line by line in the text file
  while (argv[i] != NULL) {
    printf("res[%d] = %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    i++;
  }

  delete argv;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you being forced at gunpoint to use a `char**`? C++ offers many , much simpler alternatives.

Comment: Since you are allowed to use C++ standard library classes, why not just parse into a `std::vector<std::string>` and forget about all this manual memory management?

Comment: Why don't you simply use a `std::vector<std::string>` and let it do the necessary (re-)allocations correctly for you (especially what concerns calling the copy and default consructors for the `std::string` instances correctly)?

Comment: You stuff `argv` full of pointers to memory managed by a local variable. All but one (the very last one) of these pointers are actually dangling most of the time; and when the function returns, the last one becomes dangling, too. Note how you allocate memory for `char*` pointers, but not for `char`s themselves - where do you believe is the text stored?

Comment: `argv = (char**)realloc(argv, sizeof(char*) * ++n_lines);` -- As soon as you reach for code that looks like this, rethink what you're doing -- you're supposed to be using C++, not C.  Code that looks like this would not pass most, if not every honest C++ code review (even if it worked).

Answer (score 1):

```
argv[n_lines - 1] = const_cast<char*>(para.c_str());
```

Casting away `const`-ness is already undefined behavior territory. So, this is already broken. But that's not even the major problem. The pointer returned by `c_str()` is owned by `std::string`, and is no longer valid after ***any*** subsequent modification to the `std::string`. But what does your code do next?

```
while (std::getline(file, para)) {
```

It immediately reads the next line into `para`. The previously-returned `c_str()` is no longer valid, and dereferencing it from that point is guaranteed undefined behavior, and your likely crash.

Your apparent goal is to construct a C-compatible `argv`-style array. The approach that I've used in the past, that doesn't break any rules, is to construct a

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>> argv;
```

Then have my code meticulously create each string, and explicitly `\0` terminate it. Then to construct the final C-style `argv` I simply grab the pointer to the first character of each vector, and use it to construct a

```
std::vector<char *> c_argv;
```

This does not break any rules. No tim needs to be wasted on awkward and error-prone `malloc` or `realloc` calls. The vector correctly manages all my memory for me. This is what vectors are for.